# Allowing apache access to a subdirectory in a home directory without access to the home directory

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, home-directory

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 desktop with encrypted home directories. I do development work on my computer and I want to have my webroot directory to be within my home directory so it is encrypted with the rest of my home directory. As I am the only use of the machine, I want to configure Apache to point to this directly.

Current I have changed the `/var/www` folder into a symbolic link to the workspace in my hone dir: `/home/valorin/workspace`

However, this throws **403 Forbidden** errors in apache.

I have added my user into the `www-data` group, and set the ownership & permissions on the workspace folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 valorin www-data  4096 2011-04-23 10:02 workspace
```

But the only way I can get it to work is to change my home dir group to be www-data and set permissions too. I don't really want to do this as it means Apache has access to my home dir and could possibly be used by someone on my network to get into my personal data.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What if you swap the user and group permissions?

Comment: @Justin, That still wouldn't let it into my home directory - see below, I had to set the Execute permission for all to allow access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [answered over on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36533/allowing-apache-access-to-a-subdirectory-in-a-home-directory-without-access-to-th/36535#36535) for me, but I will post here for the benefit of non-Ubuntu folks:

> You can leave your $HOME dir ownership
>   alone. You don't need to set it to
>   www-data. What you do have to do is
>   ensure that Apache has execute
>   permissions on $HOME and everything
>   above it. So, you could do something
>   like this:
>
> chmod 751 "$HOME" sudo chmod 751 /home
>
> However, the fact that $HOME is
>   encrypted might pose major problems
>   for Apache unless you can somehow
>   configure Apache to use the proper
>   decryption key.
>
> EDIT:
>
> Setting execute permissions on a
>   directory means only that you can
>   access something inside the directory
>   if you already know its name and if
>   what you're trying to access also has
>   correct permissions. So setting a
>   global x-bit on $HOME isn't too much
>   of a security risk, as long as all
>   your other files have reasonable
>   permissions. You might want to look
>   into your umask to be sure.